# InfoPath forms viewer web part

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, infopath, sharepoint-enterprise

I'd like to add a SharePoint web part in a page that would display InfoPath forms(For example Timesheet template).Does anyone know how to show the "InfoPath forms" inside web part??? Can anyone help me to provide a solution to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

There is an out of the box webpart in SharePoint 2010 for adding InfoPath forms. These forms can be integrated with lists and you can use InfoPath form views in webpart to enter data into these lists.

Here is a link which has the pictorial representation of this - http://www.chakkaradeep.com/post/SharePoint-2010-InfoPath-Form-Web-Part.aspx

Comment: In addition to this, you can put custom list forms that you have customized with InfoPath in the same web part, so that users don't have to go to the newform.aspx page.